# C - This code doesn't work when I change the amount of strings to input but works fine with a certain amount

Tags: c, console-application

forgive me if I seem to be stupid at this, I'm pretty much a beginner when it comes to C code. I genuinely want to know the reason why this particular code doesn't work if I use `#define MAXS 10` but works perfectly fine if I change it to `#define MAXS 5` or any amount below 5.

This is the code that I did which basically let the user input supposedly 10 strings and arrange them in alphabetical order then get arranged in lexicographical order and also prints out the address and string length of each string. If you're wondering why pretty much every array is done at a pointer/offset notation  is because we were told to do it that way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAXS 10 


void stringsort(char **strs){

    //for alphabetical order
    char *temp;
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<MAXS;i++)
        for(j=i+1;j<MAXS;j++){
            if(strcmp(*(strs+i),*(strs+j))>0){
                temp = *(strs+i);
                *(strs+i) = *(strs+j);
                *(strs+j) = temp;
            }
        }

    //for lexicographical order
    for(i=0; i<MAXS; i++){
        for(j=i+1;j<MAXS;j++){
            if(strlen(*(strs+i))>strlen(*(strs+j))){
                temp = *(strs+i);
                *(strs+i) = *(strs+j);
                *(strs+j) = temp;
            }
        }
    }



}

void convertosmall(char **strs){
    int i = 0, j;
    while (*(strs+i) != NULL){
        j = 0;
        while (*(*(strs+i)+j) != '\0') {
             *(*(strs+i)+j) = tolower(*(*(strs+i)+j));
             j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}



int main()
{
    char temp[25] = {0};
    char *strs[MAXS];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAXS; i++){
        printf("Input string%d: ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", temp);
        *(strs+i) = strdup(temp);
        }

    convertosmall(&strs);
    stringsort(&strs);


    printf("\nLEXICOGRAPHIC ORDERING\n\n");
    printf("STRING                      ADDRESS             LENGTH\n");
    for(i=0; i<MAXS; i++)
        printf("%-20s        %p    %-2d\n", *(strs+i), &*(strs+i), strlen(*(strs+i)));


    return 0;
}
```

I just don't understand why it works perfectly fine if I change the amount of strings to input below the amount of about 7 or something. When I try doing 10 strings, it does let me input 10 strings, but it just stops/gets an error right after I've inputted the 10 strings.

Or am I completely missing something here?

Comment: Oh also, I forgot to say that the strings are also converted into lowercase letters. Also if you spot any unnecessary code, or think this code could be cleaner -- please tell me if you have free time.

Comment: I think this is the problem: `while (*(strs+i) != NULL)`. Your other loops check for `i < MAXS`.

Comment: `while (*(strs+i) != NULL)` -- this condition in `convertosmall` assumes that you provided a NULL-terminated array of pointers.  That's _not_ the case.  `strs` only holds exactly the right number of values for your inputs, and is not terminated.  As a result, your function happily flies off the end of the array and starts reading whatever memory is there.  This is undefined behavior.

Comment: As an aside, your code will be significantly more readable if you stop using pointer arithmetic.  _e.g._ instead of `*(*(strs+i)+j)` just write `strs[i][j]` ... _please_!

Comment: @SkCrayAce: If you forgot to mention something in the question, then please [edit] your question instead of using the comments section to add additional information.

Comment: TBH that "additional information" was something we could see happening already in the code, and stating it explicitly was kinda redundant.

Comment: @paddy yeah, sorry about that, we were required to use pointer arithmetic rather than the normal index format for this particular code. Thanks so much for letting me know what the problem was!

Comment: I'd seriously consider looking for a new teacher or at least opening a debate with them.  Forcing people to write ugly code that does exactly the same thing as array syntax should be a crime.  If the goal is to teach pointer arithmetic, there are effective ways to do that but this is not one of them.